# Installing and switching to new distribution

Tags: texlive, installing, paths, distributions, update

I installed the new texlive 2022 distribution and removed the old 2021 texlive distribution with `tlmgr uninstall --all` (after verifying I was on the right distribution with `tex version` and it returned `texlive 2021`).

The 2022 distro installed successfully, but now I can’t make it work. I understand I have something to change in the `.profile` file and change the `path` and so on, which I did (see below), yet it still isn’t working.

**My `.profile` file**

```
PATH=/home/louisvgn/.local/share/applications/install-tl-20220418/1/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export PATH
INFOPATH=/home/louisvgn/.local/share/applications/install-tl-20220418/1/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
export INFOPATH
MANPATH=/home/louisvgn/.local/share/applications/install-tl-20220418/1/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export MANPATH
```

PS: I installed the distribution in the same folder as the last one which is in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: did you really install it under `install-tl-20220418` ? that looks like the temporary install directory name, not the final install location, but impossible to tell from here, texlive will install wherever you specified. Also .profile edits have no effect until you next log in.

Comment: I downloaded the the `tar.gz` file in the under `~/.local/share/applications` and from there ran the `install-tl` file. Though I asked myself the same question, was it really installed here? I don’t know the technical answer, but I presumed it was since the TL 2021 was installed here and the `path` etc. in `.profile` were written the same but with the 2021 TL path…

Comment: Also, I did re-login, I even rebooted. Plus, I just checked, but with the following command `sudo find / -name install-tl-*` it only finds occurrences in `~/.local/share/applications`. So it must be there, and I’m certain the installation was successful.

Comment: Did you install as root or as the louisvgn user? (You clearly have sudo access.) I'm not sure the installer itself is what you should be searching for. Does it install itself? I don't see why it would need to; tlmgr takes over from there. Try something like `sudo find / -iname pdflatex`.

Comment: It’s actually a Perl script… So I’m not sure sudo privileges are relevant here, is it? see : https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation

Comment: the output of `sudo find / -iname pdflatex` give `/home/louisvgn/.local/share/applications/install-tl-20210923/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`

Comment: it is a very odd install location but you could have specified that. what does `type -all pdftex` report?

Comment: I just thought knowing if you installed it as root would help narrow down where the executables might be, but it seems they are indeed in that strange location. Can you run pdflatex, etc., by specifying the full path `/home/louisvgn/.local/share/applications/install-tl-20210923/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex filename.tex`? Is the `PATH=` line in your `.profile` working? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: @frabjous I found the solution, see my solution. Although it is weird for because when I first installed it without the `sudo` option it still went through the all installation for more than one and a half hour. Yet, as you pointed out, it seems that it actually never installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple: you simply need to run the Perl script with `sudo` privileges, otherwise the installation won’t work on if you try to install it in `/usr/share/etc.` when the script takes you to the scheme page.